# best choice of a stepper motor to lift a 3kg load

Tags: motor, dc, stepper-motor

first time working with a motor.am designing an egg incubator and need a stepper motor to tilt the egg tray at 45 degree occasionally.there are two egg trays each is attached to the incubator wall and is free to rotate.the two trays are connected together such that they move together.the weight of the egg trays with eggs is 3kg. i am to use a stepper motor to push and pull the tray up and down. which stepper motor is best to lift a 3kg load? my question

Comment: Your question is not answerable. First you need to calculate needed torque based on weiggt and constuction, then time required to do that, ....

Comment: This is not a good application for a stepper motor.  Given the duration of operation, you need a means of rezeroing, so you might as well just use two limit switches and a gear motor.  You can look at belts, roller chain, a winch winding cord, or even a leadscrew if you pivot the nut.

Comment: Best choice of a stepper motor is not to choose a stepper motor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 3kg is not perfectly balanced, you're probably going to want a gearbox. I would recommend sticking with a regular size nema 17 stepper motor, and attached that either using a chain and sprocket, or for a cleaner look a timing belt and 2 pulleys.

Use a very large wheel on the rocker, and a very small wheel on the motor to create a large gear reduction.

A worm gearbox would be optimal, because it will prevent the rocker from tilting back on its own once power is removed from the motor. However, I didn't see many of those available in the right size.